# Copy objects in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to copy custom .NET objects in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Website. I have a Treeview in the website, which is supported by a .NET object. I can have multiple instances of the same website open in different Web browsers. 
I need to copy a tree node from one Web Browser to the tree view in the other web browser.  In a sense, i am copying the .NET object and constructing the tree node in the target tree. 
What are the best ways of doing it?

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by Browser, like web browser? Or some kind of Browser control?

Comment: It is terribly vague ... but we can kinda "guestimate" the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure - there are 100 different ways.

A simple example would be (if you only have 1 server running) - to just have a static variable that you assign from one browser, and then consume from another.

If you had multiple objects that you wanted to pass then you could make it a dictionary where a random ID was used as the key.

### Example

```
private static Dictionary<string, MyThingy> _store = new Dictionary<string, MyThingy>();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Store(string id, MyThingy value)
{
    _store[id] = value;

    return View();
}

public ActionResult Store(string id)
{
    return View(_store[id]);
}
```

Keep in mind the fact that you're request is very vague... and this is just an example.